# Occasional "General error" Occurs on INSERT into POSTGRES Database from Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I'm trying to insert a collection of data from Java into a Postgres database. Both the JVM and the database are 64-bit. Querying the database and viewing the output showed that the code correctly inserted 54 rows into the database before the JVM crashed. Five other entries returned identical errors, which I had logged to stderr before continuing execution. This is one of the errors, and they all have the same information:

```
Could not execute SQL insert: General error
Error code: 0
SQL State: S1000
DB Connection Status: OPEN
java.sql.SQLException: General error
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at shadowlandsCrawler.Database.storeAccount(Database.java:70)
    at shadowlandsCrawler.ShadowlandsCrawler.main(ShadowlandsCrawler.java:82)
```

I went into the shell, and I was able to manually insert the erroneous data successfully. Visual inspection of the data showed nothing other than simple ASCII. I tried closing the database connection after each insert, but the results were identical to multiple inserts on one connection.

While the JVM crashing may be related to the SQL errors, I'm only concerned right now with the cause of these exceptions, not with the crash.

Here is my database class with access details obscured:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Database {

    static Database singletonDB;
    private Connection hauntingDB;

    private PreparedStatement statement;

    private Database() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        hauntingDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:HauntingAccounts", "REDACTED", "REDACTED");
        String sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO \"Accounts\" (\"Title\", \"Author\", \"Story\", \"Words\") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
        statement = hauntingDB.prepareStatement(sqlCommand);
    }

    public static Database init() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        if(singletonDB == null){
            singletonDB = new Database();
        }

        return singletonDB;
    }

    public void close(){
        try {
            hauntingDB.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot close database, or it is already closed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public boolean storeAccount(Story hauntingAccount) throws Exception{

        boolean accountStored = false;

        System.err.println("----INSERTING ENTRY----");
        System.err.println("Title: " + hauntingAccount.getTitle());
        System.err.println("Author: " + hauntingAccount.getAuthor());
        if(hauntingAccount.getTitle().length() == 0 || hauntingAccount.getAuthor().length() == 0){
            System.err.println("URL: " + hauntingAccount.getPageURL());
            throw new Exception("TITLE OR AUTHOR IS EMPTY!!!");
        }
        try{
            statement.setString(1, hauntingAccount.getTitle());
            statement.setString(2, hauntingAccount.getAuthor());
            statement.setString(3, hauntingAccount.getStory());
            statement.setString(4, hauntingAccount.getStory().toLowerCase());
            statement.executeUpdate();
            System.err.println("SUCCESS!");
            accountStored = true;
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            String dbClosed = "UNKNOWN";
            try {
                dbClosed = hauntingDB.isClosed() ? "CLOSED" : "OPEN";
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.err.println("Could not get DB connection state.");
            }
            System.err.println("-------------------------------------------");
            System.err.println("Could not execute SQL insert: " + e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Error code: " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.err.println("SQL State: " + e.getSQLState());
            System.err.println("DB Connection Status: " + dbClosed);
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.err.println("Title: " + hauntingAccount.getTitle());
            System.err.println("Author: " + hauntingAccount.getAuthor());
            System.err.println("Page URL: " + hauntingAccount.getPageURL());
            System.err.println("-------------------------------------------");
        }
        finally{
            try {
                SQLWarning warning = statement.getWarnings();
                while (warning != null) {
                    System.err.println("-------------------------------------------");
                    System.err.println("Message: " + warning.getMessage());
                    System.err.print("Error code: " + warning.getErrorCode());
                    System.err.println("SQL State: " + warning.getSQLState());
                    System.err.println("Title: " + hauntingAccount.getTitle());
                    System.err.println("Author: " + hauntingAccount.getAuthor());
                    System.err.println("Page URL: " + hauntingAccount.getPageURL());
                    System.err.println("-------------------------------------------");
                    warning = warning.getNextWarning();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }

        return accountStored;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use the JDBC/ODBC bridge it's slow, buggy and deprecated. Use a the JDBC driver instead: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/